# Passing Value From Form to Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

The title is a little vague.  I have a form with several textboxes that require user input.  The input is all numerical.  This is a touchscreen application, so when the textbox gets focus, a "numberpad" form is displayed for the user to input the number.  The user's input is displayed on the "numberpad" form.

The question: How do I get that input to be set as the text property of the calling textbox?

I know I could pass some int value then use a big switch statement when the value is to be passed, but there are around 30 textboxes.  Any ideas?

Comment: So you're displaying a custom numberpad form when a textbox gets focus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your NumberPad form, have a property that is your result:

```
public int Result { get; private set; }
```

When the user hits the button to save the data, assign the value and set the DialogResult for the form:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Result = // whatever
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

In the calling form, check the result and only process if it is OK (in other words, the NumberPad was saved and not cancelled):

```
NumberPad pad = new NumberPad();
if (pad.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    txtBox.Text = pad.Result.ToString();
}
```